# Connecting to MariaDB using Soapui

Tags: database, soapui, mariadb

I am trying to connect to the database using SOAPUI to check if the values were updated properly. But I am having trouble doing it. Also, due to the security reasons I will need to login through SSH and we are currently using maria db(not sure which driver i use matters here)

Here is what I tried:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
def driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
def username='wonder'
def password='welcome9'
def sql = Sql.newInstance(path,username,password,driver)
def state="select * from Company"
sql.execute(state)
```

Also, Can i do this in the script assertion and where should i paste my driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the instructions to do so:

- download the driver file and its dependency libraries form [here](https://mariadb.com/products/connectors-plugins)  or pre-build jar file from [here](https://mariadb.com/my_portal/download/java-client) or from maven repository

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>xxx</version>
</dependency>
```

- copy the download jar files under SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext directory
- restart soapui tool if already running
- in the `Groovy Script` where you write the code to connect to db, first you need to register the driver using below statement:

  com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver( "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" )

So, the script may look like:

```
//Below is just a sample
//Change values as needed in below connection
def driver = 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'
def connectionString = 'jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/db'
def user = 'your_user'
def password = 'secret'
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver(driver)
def sql = Sql.newInstance(connectionString, user, password, driver)
def query = 'select * from company'
sql.execute(query)
```

For more details on mariadb, please check the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Full stack trace please?